# Why does docker-ce-3:18.09 installation on SLES 12 throw "systemd-units needed" message?

Tags: systemd, docker, sles

My goal is to install Docker 18.09 on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (SLES 12 SP3).

I can successfully download and install docker version 17.09.1_ce-98.18.1 using zypper from repositories available to me.  My goal is to install Docker version 18 and see if using that version bypasses [an intermittent bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5618#issuecomment-407751991) I see sometimes.

I have downloaded the [CentOS RPM](https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-18.09.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm) for Docker 18.09 since I don't see SLES12 as a supported binary. Other RPMs have installed in the past. The prerequisite packages (containerd.io and docker-ce-cli) install as RPMs without error.

Why does docker-ce-3:18.09 installation on SLES 12 throw "systemd-units needed" message?

I do not understand what the `systemd-units` error is here. The `systemd` package is already installed.

I believe `zypper` is complaining that `systemd` does not have any startup or unit files in the docker-ce RPM.  Is there an argument I should pass to `zypper` to unpack the systemd unit file in the correct place for SLES12?

The RPM contains `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` which I assume is the `systemd-units` file zypper is complaining about.

```
node01:~ # rpm -qa | grep -i system
systemd-228-150.40.1.x86_64
grub2-systemd-sleep-plugin-2.02-4.19.1.noarch
libboost_system1_54_0-1.54.0-26.3.1.x86_64
util-linux-systemd-2.29.2-3.5.4.x86_64
systemd-presets-branding-SLE-12.2-2.26.noarch
systemd-bash-completion-228-150.40.1.noarch
systemd-sysvinit-228-150.40.1.x86_64
libsystemd0-228-150.40.1.x86_64
filesystem-13.1-14.15.x86_64
node01:~ # zypper install   /tmp/docker-ce-18.09.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides systemd-units needed by docker-ce-3:18.09.0-3.el7.x86_64
Solution 1: do not install docker-ce-3:18.09.0-3.el7.x86_64
Solution 2: break docker-ce-3:18.09.0-3.el7.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): c
node01:~ # zypper search systemd-units
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No matching items found.
node01:~ # uname -a
Linux node01 4.4.132-94.33-default #1 SMP Tue May 29 20:09:56 UTC 2018 (76aae3b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
node01:~ # cat /etc/issue
Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l).
node01:~ #
```

---

Comment: SLES RPM packages are built differently then CentOS RPM packages, there are extensive `systemd` macros in SUSE so that `zypper` can manage systemd unit files.  Have you followed the [SLES instructions for installing Docker](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/singlehtml/book_sles_docker/book_sles_docker.html)?  The instructions say you can run `sudo zypper install docker` to install Docker after enabling the SLES container module.  If you require the newest version of Docker, it appears that Docker Enterprise supports SLES

Comment: @GracefulRestart Thanks. Docker Enterprise is not an option for me at present. I had not seen those instructions.  I will read and update my question.